# base change of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Under what kind of assumptions on $X$ and $k$ (here $X$ is a scheme over $k$ and $\bar{k}$ the algebraic closure) is the map $\mathcal{L}\mapsto \mathcal{L}\otimes_k\bar{k}$ from $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ to  $\mathrm{Pic}(X\otimes_k\bar{k})$ injective?

Comment: For example, if $X$ is proper, integral and normal, then this is true.

Comment: Why do one needs normality? Maybe proper and integral suffices...

Comment: In my proof, the normality is to insure that a rational function without zero nor pole divisor is a unit. But properness is useless.

Comment: Probably this holds for any scheme X and any field $k$.